# How to play video in swift by node js and S3

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, amazon-s3

I put my video in S3 and use node js to call it. in safari its works but in iOS app is not.

This my code on server side

```
 s3.headObject(getParams, function (err, data) {
        var stream = s3.getObject(getParams).createReadStream();

        stream.on('error', function error(err) {
            return next();
        });
        res.set('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
        res.set('Content-Length', data.ContentLength);
        res.set('Last-Modified', data.LastModified);
        res.set('ETag', data.ETag);

        stream.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Served by Amazon S3: ' + key);
        });
        stream.pipe(res);
    });
```

and This is my swift code

```
func setVideo(){
    playerViewController.view.frame = video_view.frame
    playerViewController.player = player

    self.addChild(playerViewController)
    self.video_view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
    playerViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
}

func playVideo(urlString: String) {
    
    if let videoURL = URL(string: "\(server_url)/image/\(urlString)")
    {
        print("!!url: \(videoURL)")
        self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL))
        player.play()
    }
}
```

What wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Add file extension of video i.e. `.mp4` at the last of `URL`.

**FYI**

`AVPlayerItem` cannot create objects from a `URL` that points to a `Data` file. You need to have a `URL` with the file extension like ".mp4" for video type

Comment: if let videoURL = URL(string:"https://-------/1_02.mp4") I already have it. one problem that I found is my ole work on iOS14 is works but in iOS 15 since Xcode13 is now works.